# sorting elements from xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, sorting, indexing, bubble-sort

i want to sort elements in xml file according to chosen algorithm type by user in java.i have merged xml  file which contains 10 xml files. so it will be like first user select type of algorithm and then program sort elements as user wants.how can i do this? pls help me

here is how i merged xml files

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Merge2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sourceFile1Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers1.xml";
    String sourceFile2Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers2.xml";
    String sourceFile3Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers3.xml";
    String sourceFile4Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers4.xml";
    String sourceFile5Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers5.xml";
    String sourceFile6Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers6.xml";
    String sourceFile7Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers7.xml";
    String sourceFile8Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers8.xml";
    String sourceFile9Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers9.xml";
    String sourceFile10Path = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers10.xml";

    String mergedFilePath = "C:\\Users\\project\\mergedXML.xml";

    File[] files = new File[10];
    files[0] = new File(sourceFile1Path);
    files[1] = new File(sourceFile2Path);
    files[2] = new File(sourceFile3Path);
    files[3] = new File(sourceFile4Path);
    files[4] = new File(sourceFile5Path);
    files[5] = new File(sourceFile6Path);
    files[6] = new File(sourceFile7Path);
    files[7] = new File(sourceFile8Path);
    files[8] = new File(sourceFile9Path);
    files[9] = new File(sourceFile10Path);


    File mergedFile = new File(mergedFilePath);

    mergeFiles(files, mergedFile);
}
public static void mergeFiles(File[] files, File mergedFile) {

    FileWriter fstream = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, true);
         out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (File f : files) {
        System.out.println("merging: " + f.getName());
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(aLine);
                out.newLine();
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

and my merged xml file starts like below

```
<numberList>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<number index="1">770820</number>
<number index="2">640903</number>
<number index="3">997132</number>
<number index="4">193504</number>
```

i want to show it like

```
 <numberList>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<number index="1">193504</number>
<number index="2">640903</number>
<number index="3">770820</number>
<number index="4">997132</number>
```

Comment: You should use arrays (or collections) and loops instead of copying/pasting lines of code. By the way, I don(t get what you want to do after merging the files.

Comment: but i dont want to change index part,could you show me how can i do it pls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the sort thing but just for you to know, your code could be far more concise :

```
String pathTemplate   = "C:\\Users\\project\\Numbers%d.xml";
String mergedFilePath = "C:\\Users\\project\\mergedXML.xml";
int    nFiles         = 10;
File[] files          = new File[nFiles];

for (int i=0 ; i<nFiles ; i++)
   files[i] = new File(String.format(pathTemplate,i + 1));
//...
```

If you explain clearer your problem about sorting the merge file I'll complete my answer.

Comment: thank you for reply, i have xml file which starts like above, and  what i want to do is that user selects a type of algorithm ,then when user selected algorithm type,elements in xml file will be sorted according to chosen algorithm,lets say bubble or other,and thne show sorted elements,but i couldnt fix that part :s

Comment: It is not that hard... just implement all the sorting algorithms you want to propose to the user, retrieve all the values of the merged file in an ArrayList, sort it and write in an output file. Which part of it are you unable to do.

Comment: retrieve all the values of the merged file in an ArrayList :(

Comment: You know how to read a file, and there are plenty of libraries that enable working with XML in Java. This should not be a problem.